# Query about Personal Accident cover

Tags: india, insurance

I work in a MNC in India. I have a query about Personal Accident cover. I read in a ET article as 'cheap and essential'. When I asked around about this with few individuals, they advised to buy add-ons for my existing term life insurance policy, as I had bought these addons.

I believe a term plan should be a term plan. I would like to compare these addons with standalone personal accident covers.

Can anyone suggest how much amount should be the cover for.

Edit: I know these are useful. However, I'm having difficulty in buying one of these in **India**. Could not find any names in searching the internet too and hence am asking for help on what these are called here. I hope giving a few names would not make it too specific about a single product of a Personal accident cover plan. Hope the question is more clear now.

Comment: Questions asking for specific product recommendations (e.g., particular insurance policies) are off-topic here.  The rest of your question is somewhat unclear.  Are you just asking if it makes financial sense to purchase personal injury coverage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Person accident coverage is advised for some one with high risk of accident's, say someone in sales job travelling around most of time.

The additional benefits is typically if you're partially disabled, it gives you a lumpsum amount that neither your term insurance may give nor medical insurance may give.

Note one could be disabled with out any accident and this is not covered.

All leading Govt insurance company like New India, orient or private player like HDFC Ergo offer these plans.

There is no recommended levels. However some companies restrict the sum insured to 72 months of salary, while others put a total Max cap on the amount for which such policy is issued.

Comment: If you conclude that you need more insurance than the normal maximum, investigate "umbrella" policies, if they are available in your area.